# How should I expose read-only fields from Python classes?

Tags: python

I have many different small classes which have a few fields each, e.g. this:

```
class Article:
    def __init__(self, name, available):
        self.name = name
        self.available = available
```

What's the easiest and/or most idiomatic way to make the `name` field read only, so that

```
a = Article("Pineapple", True)
a.name = "Banana"  # <-- should not be possible
```

is not possible anymore?

Here's what I considered so far:

1. Use a getter (ugh!).

   ```
   class Article:
       def __init__(self, name, available):
           self._name = name
           self.available = available

       def name(self):
           return self._name
   ```

   Ugly, non-pythonic - and a lot of boilerplate code to write (especially if I have multiple fields to make read-only). However, it does the job and it's easy to see why that is.
2. Use [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/attribute-access.html):

   ```
   class Article:
       def __init__(self, name, available):
           self.name = name
           self.available = available

       def __setattr__(self, name, value):
           if name == "name":
               raise Exception("%s property is read-only" % name)
           self.__dict__[name] = value
   ```

   Looks pretty on the caller side, seems to be the idiomatic way to do the job - but unfortunately I have many classes with only a few fields to make read only each. So I'd need to add a `__setattr__` implementation to all of them. Or use some sort of mixin maybe? In any case, I'd need to make up my mind how to behave in case a client attempts to assign a value to a read-only field. Yield some exception, I guess - but which?
3. Use a utility function to define properties (and optionally getters) automatically. This is basically the same idea as (1) except that I don't write the getters explicitely but rather do something like

   ```
   class Article:
       def __init__(self, name, available):
           # This function would somehow give a '_name' field to self
           # and a 'name()' getter to the 'Article' class object (if
           # necessary); the getter simply returns self._name
           defineField(self, "name")
           self.available = available
   ```

   The downside of this is that I don't even know if this is possible (or how to implement it) since I'm not familiar with runtime code generation in Python. :-)

So far, (2) appears to be most promising to me except for the fact that I'll need `__setattr__` definitions to all my classes. I wish there was a way to 'annotate' fields so that this happens automatically. Does anybody have a better idea?

For what it's worth, I'mu sing Python 2.6.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all the interesting responses! By now, I have this:

```
def ro_property(o, name, value):
    setattr(o.__class__, name, property(lambda o: o.__dict__["_" + name]))
    setattr(o, "_" + name, value)

class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, name, available):
        ro_property(self, "name", name)
        self.available = available
```

This seems to work quite nicely. The only changes needed to the original class are

- I need to inherit `object` (which is not such a stupid thing anyway, I guess)
- I need to change `self._name = name` to `ro_property(self, "name", name)`.

This looks quite neat to me - can anybody see a downside with it?

Comment: Your `ro_property` is way too complicated -- either Sven's or Chris's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @EthanFurman it is tricky, but maybe that is the price you have to pay if you would like to keep the changes done to existing classes to the minimum?

Comment: I can't actually remember when I last wrote to an instance's attribute (from outside the instance's methods), except when monkey-patching someone else's code. Aren't instance attributes almost always meant to be read-only in practice? Instance attributes are typically set in `__init__` and not changed afterwards, unless by calling a method on the instance. I guess I consider this proper coding style.

Comment: Summarized: I have the feeling *most* (but not all) instance attributes are intended to be read-only. So if you are writing to an instance attribute, you better make sure that you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would use [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) as a decorator to manage your getter for `name` (see the example for the class `Parrot` in the documentation). Use, for example, something like:

```
class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, name, available):
        self._name = name
        self.available = available

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

If you do not define the setter for the `name` property (using the decorator `x.setter` around a function) this throws an `AttributeError` when you try and reset `name`.

<strike>**Note**: You have to use Python's new-style classes (i.e. in Python 2.6 you have to inherit from `object`) for properties to work correctly.</strike> This is not the case according to @SvenMarnach.

Comment: This looks pretty on the caller side, but it still looks like boiler plate when actually writing the classes. It would be beautiful if I could do something like `@property self_name = name` or so in the constructor so that Python would define the getter for me automatically. As it is, this code is nicer for the caller, but even more code to write for the class author than a plain getter (the extra line for `@property`).

Comment: Something like `@property self._name = name` would be nice, but decorators work on functions rather than objects. It is an extra line on your getter idea, but this is the idiomatic way of doing it, and the way the Python documentation demonstrates creating read-only class variables. Ultimately you will always need some boilerplate code to redefine the default behaviour of class variables.

Comment: [Properties also work on old-style classes.](http://ideone.com/wgXAX)  The descriptor itself, i.e. the class `property` itself, must be a new-style class, but it is.  The Python documentation is a bit misleading in this regard.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for that - I am obviously mistaken and have updated my answer.

Comment: Accepting this; it's not as compact as other answers (or what I came up with myself by now) but it seems that this is the best solution overall: it's not too noisy and it's idiomatic. As @SvenMarnach put it: "Everyone familiar with Python will recognize this pattern, and there's no domain-specific voodoo happening."

Comment: @SvenMarnach To be exact, this only holds for the getting part. For having a setter, the object holding the property must be new style. AFAIK, for deleters as well.

Answer (score 17):

As pointed out in other answers, using a property is the way to go for read-only attributes.  The solution in [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920797/279627) is the cleanest one:  It uses the `property()` built-in in a straight-forward, simple way.  Everyone familiar with Python will recognize this pattern, and there's no domain-specific voodoo happening.

If you don't like that every property needs three lines to define, here's another straight-forward way:

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, name, available):
        self._name = name
        self.available = available
    name = property(attrgetter("_name"))
```

Generally, I don't like defining domain-specific functions to do something that can be done easily enough with standard tools.  Reading code is so much easier if you don't have to get used to all the project-specific stuff first.

Comment: Your reasoning about *why* Chris' answer is so good really won me over. I thought that some clever trick along the lines of what rodrigo posted would be really neat but indeed, I did get some raised eyebrows for so much magic in one place.

Answer (score 8):

Based in the Chris answer, but arguably more pythonic:

```
def ro_property(field):
    return property(lambda self : self.__dict__[field])

class Article(object):
    name = ro_property('_name')

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "banana"
```

If trying to modify the property it will raise an `AttributeError`.

```
a = Article()
print a.name # -> 'banana'
a.name = 'apple' # -> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

**UPDATE**: About your updated answer, the (little) problem I see is that you are modifying the definition of the property in the class *every* time you create an instance. And I don't think that is such a good idea. That's why I put the `ro_property` call outside of the `__init__` function

What about?:

```
def ro_property(name):
    def ro_property_decorator(c):
        setattr(c, name, property(lambda o: o.__dict__["_" + name]))
        return c
    return ro_property_decorator

@ro_property('name')
@ro_property('other')
class Article(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._other = "foo"

a = Article("banana")
print a.name # -> 'banana'
a.name = 'apple' # -> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Class decorators are fancy!

Comment: I like how this reduces the amount of change to be done to the classes.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer, please see my updated answer for what I now have. It achieves just what I need I think, and the chagne to the original class is just one line (instead of `self._prop = prop` I now do `ro_property(self, "prop", prop)`).

Comment: Oh, your concern regarding my current solution makes total sense (I was thinking of it myself when writing the code). I really like your new version, it has a very "declarative" touch to it. :-)

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the class decorator solution is that it places the decorator far from the actual attribute.

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that it's *always* possible to modify attributes of an object in Python - there are no truly private variables in Python. It's just that some approaches make it a bit harder. But a determined coder can always lookup and modify the value of an attribute. For example, I can always modify your `__setattr__` if I want to...

For more information, see [Section 9.6](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) of The Python Tutorial. Python uses name mangling when attributes are prefixed with `__` so the actual name at runtime is different but you could still derive what that name at runtime is (and thus modify the attribute).

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with your option 1 but refined it to use Python property:

```
class Article
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    name = property(get_name)
```

Comment: Double underscores are to prevent subclasses accidentally overriding fields. For regular "private" fields the single underscore is correct. Also, it's better to use `property` as a decorator.

Comment: Hm, sounds interestinig (especially if I could pass a lambda to `property`...), but I can't seem to get it working. `get_name` would be a global method, and the `name` assignment would be done in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks agf. The above code should be placed within your class, not globally.

Comment: I'd always use double `__` for "private", how do you know someone who subclassed yours previously hasn't already used `_name` as a "protected" member?