# __setattr__ method to ensure objects in the class are immutable

Tags: python, immutability, setattr

I have the following class defined (a big part of it shortened down) but my main question is once an object of this class is defined with its initalized variables I want to make sure that these variables are unchangeable from outside of the class... If such an attempt is made I will need to raise an AssertionError.. I have the **setattr** method defined to raise this exception but after putting this method in it completely destroys previous instances and tests I have been doing with this class raising this same AssertionError whenever an attempt to create an object of this class is made...So here is a dramatically reduced version of my class.

```
class Interval:
    compare_mode = None 

    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min 
        self.max = max 

    def min_max(min, max = None)-> 'Interval Object':
    .
    .
    .
    return Interval(min, max)
```

all other class methods...

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):

    raise AssertionError('Objects in this class are immutable')
```

so once I try to test muting objects out of this class I get wrong exceptions on top of destroying previous tests with the rest of my methods in this class..

```
p.min = 0;  raised wrong exception(NameError)
p.max = 0;  raised wrong exception(NameError)
p.HeyImChangingYourMethodandThereIsNothingYouCanDoToStopME  raised wrong exception(NameError)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I expose read-only fields from Python classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920677/how-should-i-expose-read-only-fields-from-python-classes)

Answer (score 2):

You're question is a little hard to follow -- However, in `__init__`, you do something like:

```
self.max = 0
```

This will call `__setattr__` which will raise your exception on the spot.

If you really want immutability, you could consider using a `collections.namedtuple` + `__slots__`:

```
class Interval(collections.namedtuple('IntervalBase', 'min,max')):
    __slots__ = ()
    def method1(self):
        print self.min
        print self.max
```

As a demo:

```
>>> class Interval(collections.namedtuple('IntervalBase', 'min,max')):
...     __slots__ = ()
...     def method1(self):
...         print self.min
...         print self.max
... 
>>> Interval(1,2)
IntervalBase(min=1, max=2)
>>> Interval(1,2).method1
<bound method Interval.method1 of IntervalBase(min=1, max=2)>
>>> Interval(1,2).method1()
1
2
>>> Interval(1,2).foo = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Interval' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Note that a user could still add attributes to a subclass of `Interval` however unless that subclass also used `__slots__` ...

---

Also note that usually you shouldn't care if a user adds add-hoc attributes to your instance.  If none of the API provided methods can change (which you can enforce via `property`), then for all intents and purposes, your class is *immutable* and you can then open up the world that immutability provides (reasonably defined `__hash__` for example).

Comment: As I remember, if you once define __slots__ = (), you will not be able to add fields on subclassing

Comment: @akaRem -- You can (try it :).  Subclasses don't inherit their parent's `__slots__`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__setattr__` will also prevent the object from setting its own attributes, for instance the `self.min` and `self.max` that you set in `__init__`.

If you want to avoid this, set a flag at the end of `__init__` that tells whether the object is initialized, and have `__setattr__` check this flag and not allow setting if the flag is set.  Or, have your `__init__` set the attributes by directly modifying `self.__dict__` (e.g., `self.__dict__['min'] = min`).

If you only have a few of these properties to initialize, it may be more readable to use `property` and define a getter-only property for each one.  However, unlike using `__setattr__`, this will not prevent users from adding new attributes to your class.

Comment: so for the two attributes in my init method add them to self.__dict__ ? i actually did that by adding my them in (self.__dict__['min'] = min
self.__dict__['max'] = max) and checked in my __setattr__ method that if the values passed into it was not within this dictionary then raise the AssertionError