# Trying to create read-only slots using metaclasses

Tags: python

I wrote some code based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920677/how-should-i-expose-read-only-fields-from-python-classes), and [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/197965-simple-read-only-attributes-with-meta-class-progra/).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class ROSlotsType(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        roprops = namespace.pop("__roslots__")
        namespace["__slots__"] = tuple(("_" + propname) for propname in roprops)
        for propname in roprops:
            namespace[propname] = property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_" + propname)) # can't use self.__dict__ since it doesn't exist
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class Location(metaclass = ROSlotsType):
    __roslots__ = ["lat", "lon", "alt"]
    def __init__(self, lat, lon, alt = 0):
        self._lat = lat ; self._lon = lon ; self._alt = alt
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Location({}, {}, {})".format(self._lat, self._lon, self._alt)

place = Location(25.282, 82.956, 77.0)
print("Created object {}".format(place))

print("Accessing its attributes:", place.lat, place.lon, place.alt)

print("Trying to access its __dict__...")
try: place.__dict__
except:
    print("Caught exception; object has only __slots__: {}".format(place.__slots__))

print("Trying to set new property...")
try: place.name = "Varanasi"
except:
    print("Caught exception; cannot add new property")

print("Trying to modify read-only property...")
try: place.alt += 1
except:
    print("Caught exception; cannot modify read-only property")
```

Executing the above gives:

```
Created object Location(25.282, 82.956, 77.0)
Accessing its attributes: 77.0 77.0 77.0
Trying to access its __dict__...
Caught exception; object has only __slots__: ('_lat', '_lon', '_alt')
Trying to set new property...
Caught exception; cannot add new property
Trying to modify read-only property...
Caught exception; cannot modify read-only property
```

The slots and read-only behaviour work fine, but apparently there is some problem with the property getters, since while `__repr__` which uses `_lat` and `_lon` directly is giving the correct values, the attribute accesses using `place.lat` and `place.lon` are instead giving the value of `place.alt`.

Please advise me on what is wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lambda` here creates an anonymous function:

```
namespace[propname] = property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_" + propname))
```

That function references `propname`, which is a local variable of the function in which it was defined.  Unfortunately, it's not copying the `propname` value at that moment—it's keeping a *reference* to that `propname` variable, and once you get around to actually using that function, the `for` loop has completed and `propname` is left with the last value in `roprops`; namely, `alt`.

To fix this, you can use a somewhat-hacky-but-widely-recognized way of capturing it by value rather than by reference: create a parameter that shadows the other variable, but with a default value with the value you want:

```
namespace[propname] = property(lambda self, propname=propname: getattr(self, "_" + propname))
```

As [Karl Knechtel mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707763/trying-to-create-read-only-slots-using-metaclasses/23707776?noredirect=1#comment36433265_23707776), you can also use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), which eliminates the hacky bits altogether:

```
namespace[propname] = property(operator.attrgetter('_' + propname))
```

Lastly, as your question was originally posted on Code Review, I'd note that you should probably run your code through [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8).

Comment: In this particular case, might I suggest `namespace[propname] = property(operator.attrgetter('_' + propname))`? It's also worth mentioning `functools.partial` here, although unfortunately it's not the first argument we want to bind this time.