# Creating a property for Python Class instance

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

I am learning how to code in Python.
 I have created a Bandwidth class, which has _get_bandwidth and _set_bandwidth private methods. Created a property for bandwidth used. Not sure how to create a property, which when called on the Bandwidth object, will give the percentage of used bandwidth. See code below, thank you.

```
class Bandwidth():
    def __init__(self, total_bandwidth, used_bandwidth = 0):
        self.total_bandwidth = total_bandwidth
        self._used_bandwidth = used_bandwidth

    #get used bandwidth    
    def _get_bandwidth(self):
        return self._used_bandwidth

    #set bandwidth
    def _set_bandwidth(self, bandwidth):
        if bandwidth < self.total_bandwidth:
            self._used_bandwidth = bandwidth

    bandwidth_used = property(_get_bandwidth, _set_bandwidth)


    # A percentage property that calculates how much bandwidth has been used
    # The percentage property should be read-only.

    #percentage = property()



lebara = Bandwidth(8)
lebara.bandwidth_used = 2
# print(lebara.percentage) # should give 0.25

# lebara.bandwidth_used = 4
# print(lebara.percentage) # should give 0.5

# lebara.bandwidth_used = 10 # _bandwidth used should not change because there's only 8 bits in a byte
# print(lebara.percentage) #  should give 0.5
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I expose read-only fields from Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920677/how-should-i-expose-read-only-fields-from-python-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@property` decorator to modify the behavior of a getter, and access it like you would access an attribute. In the same vein, you use `@attribute.getter` decorator to mimic the behavior of directly setting the value of an attribute:

In your example:

```
class Bandwidth():
    def __init__(self, total_bandwidth, used_bandwidth=0):
        self._total_bandwidth = total_bandwidth
        self._used_bandwidth = used_bandwidth

    @property
    def used_bandwidth(self):
        return self._used_bandwidth

    @used_bandwidth.setter
    def used_bandwidth(self, bw):
        if 0 < bw <= self._total_bandwidth:
            self._used_bandwidth = bw

    @property
    def pcent_used(self):
        print(f'used_bandwidth: {self.used_bandwidth}, total_bandwidth: {self._total_bandwidth}')
        return (self.used_bandwidth / self._total_bandwidth) * 100  #<-- remove * 100 if you need a decimal between 0 and 1


lebara = Bandwidth(8)
lebara.used_bandwidth = 2
print(lebara.pcent_used) # should give 25

lebara.used_bandwidth = 4
print(lebara.pcent_used) # should give 50

lebara.used_bandwidth = 10
print(lebara.pcent_used) # should give 50   # remains unchanged
```

#### output:

```
used_bandwidth: 2, total_bandwidth: 8
25.0
used_bandwidth: 4, total_bandwidth: 8
50.0
used_bandwidth: 4, total_bandwidth: 8
50.0
```